# Find all the prerequisites for a course without using recursive CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

Given a table:

```
Course code | course needed
---------------------------
2           | 1
3           | 2
4           | 3
4           | 7
5           | 4
6           | 5
```

I need to find all the pre-requisites of course 5, so eg. the answer I should get is course code: 4, 7, 3, 2, 1.

Is there any way to do this **without recursive CTE**? Thank you. At the moment I think the only viable solution is to use join, but I'm still not too sure.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options for doing this are:

1. Using a recursive CTE.
2. Using similar hierarchical functionality, supported by some databases, such as Oracle.
3. Using a loop in a scripting language or application language.
4. Using a loop in a stored procedure or a recursive stored procedure (or perhaps user-defined function).
5. Explicit joins or similar logic, if you know the maximum depth of the recursive relationship.

The recursive CTE is the only approach that provides a general, single-query solution to the problem using standard(ish) SQL where you don't know now deep the prerequisite graph goes.

If you want to go down the route of explicit logic, one method is:

```
select t.course_needed
from t
where t.course = 5 or
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.course_needed = t.course and
                    t2.course = 5
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from t t2 join
                   t t3
                   on t3.course_needed = t2.course
              where t2.course_needed = t.course and
                    t3.course = 5
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from t t2 join
                   t t3
                   on t3.course_needed = t2.course join
                   t t4
                   on t4.course_needed = t3.course
              where t2.course_needed = t.course and
                    t4.course = 5
             ) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=730fd41bfb00e0c0dca5e6ece78bebb1) is a db<>fiddle that illustrates this.

Comment: If I know how deep is the recursive relationship and want to use join, do you have any idea on how I can start? Thank you. Sorry I'm still learning about database